# Disk_Utilisation_Linux(Find highest disk utilization by file)

Tags: bash

I want to check the disk utilization through 'df -h' in this on the basis of 5th column 'used%' i want to compare with some threshold like '80'. if $5 > threshold than enter to that file system.

please anyone help me.

Answer (score 2):

### With only 1 fork to  `df`:

Something like:

```
treshold=80
{ read _
  while read dev tot use fre pct fs;do
      if [ "${pct%\%}" -gt $treshold ] ;then
          echo "Warning: $dev: $use/$tot use $pct on '$fs'"
      fi
  done
 } < <(df -h)
```

In a script, you could use:

```
#!/bin/bash

treshold=80
exec {dfout}< <(df -h)
read -u $dfout headline
while read -u $dfout dev tot use fre pct fs;do
    if [ "${pct%\%}" -gt $treshold ] ;then
        echo "Warning: $dev: $use/$tot use $pct on '$fs'"
    fi
done
exec {dfout}<&-
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(df -h |awk 'NR!=1 && $5>="80%" {print $6}');do echo $i;done
```

or

```
for i in $(df -h |awk 'NR!=1 && $5>="80%" {print $6}')
do      
     echo $i
     echo "Hello-World"
#and-do-this cd $i
#and-do-etc
done
```